# Flutter iOS How to show download notification success?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, file, download

I am downloading a file using **FlutterDownloader**.

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: url,
  savedDir: (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path,
  showNotification:
      true, // show download progress in the status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification:
      true, // click on the notification to open the downloaded file (for Android)
);
```

In Android, the notification shows in the notification bar. But in iOS no notification shows even though the file is successfully downloaded and is showing in the "Files" app under the project name.

Solution needed: How to show the download notification in iOS or a snack bar with the link to the iOS phone "Files" app under the project folder.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Awais Ahmad, Did you solved this issue? If yes, Please guide me. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: use native iOS method invoke.

Comment: Did you get the answer or not? please let me know @Awais Ahmad

Comment: Did you find the solution? @Awais Ahmed, I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flutter dio package which has a download function with progress callbacks. Set the total length by setting content length in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not show your progress in IOS notification because the OS(Operating System) doesn't let third-party apps to access the notification directly, but you can do it by `SnackBar` instead:

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: url,
  savedDir: (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path,
  showNotification:
      true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification:
      true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);

_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    content: Text('Download completed'),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'Open',
      onPressed: () async {
        // Open the downloaded file in the Files app
        await OpenFile.open('${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/$taskId.pdf');
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

As you know, `_scaffoldKey` is defined in `Scaffold` as a `Key`.

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: url,
  savedDir: (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path,
  showNotification:
      true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification:
      true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);

_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    content: Text('Download completed'),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'Open',
      onPressed: () async {
        // Open the downloaded file in the Files app
        await OpenFile.open('${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/$taskId.pdf');
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and formatting to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: How can you be so sure that the file has finished downloading? You showed the "Download completed" snackbar right after you put the download into queue. Depending on user's internet connection, the download probably has just started.